# Python, read CRLF text file as is, with CRLF

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, line-endings

```
with open(fn, 'rt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

This reads CR LF text file (WinXP, Py 2.6) with LF line ends. So `lines` contain '\n' ends. How to get lines as is:

- for CRLF file get lines with '\n\r' ends
- for LF file get lines with '\n' ends

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of the built-in `open()` function, use [`io.open()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open). This gives you more control over how newlines are handled with the `newline` argument:

```
import io

with io.open(fn, 'rt', newline='') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

Setting `newline` to the empty string, leaves universal newline support enabled but returns line endings untranslated; you can still use `.readlines()` to find lines terminated with any of the legal line terminators but the data returned is exactly that found in the file:

> On input, if newline is `None`, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`, and these are translated into `'\n'` before being returned to the caller. If it is `''`, universal newlines mode is enabled, but **line endings are returned to the caller untranslated**.

Emphasis mine.

This is different from opening the file in binary mode, where `.readlines()` will only split the file on `\n` characters. For a file with `\r` line endings or mixed line endings, this means that lines are not going to be split correctly.

Demo:

```
>>> import io
>>> open('test.txt', 'wb').write('One\nTwo\rThree\r\n')
>>> open('test.txt', 'rb').readlines()
['One\n', 'Two\rThree\r\n']
>>> io.open('test.txt', 'r', newline='').readlines()
[u'One\n', u'Two\r', u'Three\r\n']
```

Note that `io.open()` also decodes file contents to unicode values.

Comment: This is great! But looking at the 3.5 docs, I find that the built-in ´open()` has the same support for the `newline` parameter. Maybe that changed sometime in the past?

Comment: I only now see that the OP asked for a 2.x solution.

Comment: @cxxl: this question is specific to Python 2.x, yes, where the built-in `open` is not the same function. In Python 3.x `io.open` and `open` are the exact same function.