# How to use regex to escape some info in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file and I read that using Python. It starts with a web address and provides other info starts with (y) or (n). Between the lines, there might be few  blank lines. For example the text file can be like this,

```
http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/money/industries/energy/2005-12-28-enron-participants_x.htm

(y) Lay, Kenneth
(y) Skilling, Jeffrey
(n) Howard, Kevin
(n) Krautz, Michael
```

I would like have the names starts with (y) and returns as list. Say, for this case the return list would be like this,

```
result = ["Lay, Kenneth", "Skilling, Jeffrey"]
```

I read the data as following,

```
poi_names_data = open("../final_project/poi_names.txt", "r")

for row in poi_names_data:
    print row, "\n"
```

How to extract the right info from the row?

Comment: `if row.startswith('(y)'): print row` – take that for a start, and then try to solve it yourself.

Comment: Or [`if row.startswith("(y) "): print(row[4:])`](https://ideone.com/dPb3EB). Do you need  to somehow link the `(y)` strings to the address under which they appear?

Comment: What's the point of down voting when I have 2 answers and almost no other objections about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you can use `startswith` to decide if you are going to process the row and use `re.sub` to remove `(y)`, leading spaces and line breaks `\n`, after that it should give you the expected output:

```
import re
result = []
with open("test.txt") as text:
    for row in text:
        if row.startswith("(y)"):
            result.append(re.sub(r"\(y\)\s+|\n", "", row))

result

# ['Lay, Kenneth', 'Skilling, Jeffrey']
```

Comment: You are trying to remove a newline symbol from a line with `re.sub` and `r"\(y\)\s+|\n"` pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Every row does contain a new line symbol?

Comment: Ok, there are 2 possible alternatives: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350305/python-read-crlf-text-file-as-is-with-crlf, 2) `strip`. Also, why not use `res.append()`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I agree with the `res.append()` part and the alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend read file line by line and process accordingly. The reason is that if your file is big, really big then it will be much better performance and less memory footprint.

```
import io
import re

result = []
rx = re.compile(r'(?<=\(y\)).*', re.MULTILINE)

with open('data.txt','r+') as f:
    for line in f:
        match = rx.search(line)
        if match:
            result.append(match.group(0).strip())

print(result)
```

I'll get following output from your sample data. (assuming data is stored in file `test.txt`)

```
['Lay, Kenneth', 'Skilling, Jeffrey']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Someone intentionally downvoted this legit question without providing any valid reason. Can you help me out upvoting ?

Comment: I didn't down voted but I think someone thought this question is very basic and you didn't showed your effort to solve it except asking what solution you want.

Comment: I'm new in Python and don't know enough regex to solve it. Certainly it's possible to approach without using regex though.