# ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators

Tags: python, python-3.x

Good evening,

I'm currently enrolled in an introduction-course to python and have come across an issue that I haven't been able to solve. I'm sure it's a simple error somewhere in my code, but I haven't been able to find any questions on SO that solved my issue.

*Strangely enough it compiles and runs fine when executing it from cygwin...*

**I'm getting this error while validating through 3rd party tests (that I don't have access to):**

> Python script, ASCII text executable, with CRLF line terminators

This is my code:

```
    height = float(input("What is the plane's elevation in metres? \r\n"))
    height = format(height * 3.28084, '.2f')

    speed = float(input("What is the plane's speed in km/h? \r\n"))
    speed = format(speed * 0.62137, '.2f')

    temperature = float(input("Finally, what is the temperature (in celsius) outside? \r\n"))
    temperature = format(temperature * (9/5) + 32, '.2f') 

    print("""\n########### OUTPUT ###########\n\nThe elevation is {feet} above the sea level, \n
you are going {miles} miles/h, \n
finally the temperature outside is {temp} degrees fahrenheit \n
########### OUTPUT ###########""".format(feet=height, miles=speed, temp=temperature))
```

And this is a cgi based on it (both are throwing the same error):

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 


# To write pagecontent to sys.stdout as bytes instead of string
import sys
import codecs


#Enable debugging of cgi-.scripts
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()


# Send the HTTP header
#print("Content-Type: text/plain;charset=utf-8")
print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print("")


height = format(1100 * 3.28084, '.2f')

speed = format(1000 * 0.62137, '.2f')

temperature = format(-50 * (9/5) + 32, '.2f')


toPrint = """\n########### OUTPUT ###########\n\nThe elevation is {feet} above the sea level, \n
you are going {miles} miles/h, \n
finally the temperature outside is {temp} degrees fahrenheit \n
########### OUTPUT ###########"""

toPrint.format(feet=height, miles=speed, temp=temperature)

# Here comes the content of the webpage 
content = """<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Min redovisnings-sida</title>
<pre>
<h1>Min Redovisnings-sida </h1>




</pre>

<body>
 {printer}
</body>

"""


# Write page content
sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
sys.stdout.write(content.format(printer=toPrint))
```

Comment: Had hoped using something like this would solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20350305/python-read-crlf-text-file-as-is-with-crlf

Comment: the crlf line terminators are not the `\r\n` inside your strings. they're literally the terminators of the lines in the containing text file. e.g. you wrote this code on a Windows system.

Comment: I figured as much... It's the infamous indentation, then?

Comment: That output is the output of the linux/unix `file` command, which analyzes a file to determine what it is.  Something somewhere - presumably the testbed you mentioned - is running the `file` command and returning its output.  Do you trust the 3rd party tests?  (i.e., do you know that they work properly?)

Comment: So would something like this be solved if I used a virtualbox to either write it manually or copy&paste it to a text-editor and then let it be tested?

Or is there any easier way?

Comment: Also doesn't cygwin emulate a linux terminal? Meaning it would be compiling and executing the .py and .cgi as an emulation of linux/unix and as such would catch the errors too? :/

Comment: That's the thing - as far as I can tell (and supported by the fact that "it runs fine when executing it from cygwin"), this isn't an error in your code.  Nothing in your code should produce that output.  The 3rd party test program seems buggy, or the way you're submitting your code to it is wrong.  The code itself - while there are lots of recommendations for improvement we could make - seems acceptable enough.

Comment: Strange... Well I suppose I'll have to check with the professor. Thanks tho! :)

Comment: Are you sure what you're getting is an error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to convert CRLF to LF, to do so you can run this command:

```
dos2unix your_file
```

If you need to apply that to a specific folder content, use the below command inside your folder:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

You need to install **dos2unix** package first:

```
sudo apt-get install dos2unix
```

Comment: This may be an interested test.  If you do run dos2unix and submit your code, it's likely that you'll get an "error" that says `Python script, ASCII text executable`.  Doing this would confirm that it has nothing to do with the `\r\n` and instead is an issue with the tester or how you're using it.

Comment: That's normally what I do when I run into this issue (when I copy files from Windows to Ubuntu), so I run these commands then I push my code to remote servers using Git.

Comment: There is also `dos2unix` for MacOS: `brew install dos2unix`