# Two identical commands give different output

Tags: bash, scripting

I have two text files file1.txt and file2.txt. Both have a simple structure which is like:

```
site_j-hostname1
<output of ifconfig>

site_j-hostname2
<output of ifconfig>

.
.
.
site_j-hostnamen
<output of ifconfig>
```

Two sites so j in {1,2}. From such text files, I want to produce a series of rows each with this structure (there's only one MAC on these outputs):

```
<hostname>,<mac address>
```

On CetOS 8, I came up with:

```
for host in $(grep site_j-hostname filej.txt); do row="$host,"; row+=$(grep -A3 -w $host filej.txt | grep -m1 ether | xargs | cut -d ' ' -f2); echo $row; done
```

On one file, this returned the expected output. The other returned something like (different MACs, x is just a placeholder to not put the actual MACs):

```
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
,xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

The only difference between these is that one file was generated in a Unix system, put into a .tgz file and sent to me. The other was downloaded to Windows, put into a .rar file and sent to me.

Running `file` on them gives

```
ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators
```

on one and

```
ASCII text
```

on the other.

Is it possible to fix the above so that it works all the time?

Comment: If you have pasted that `ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators` with your favorite web search engine, e.g. google, then you would have seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301086/ascii-text-executable-with-crlf-line-terminators

Comment: See: [How to convert Windows end of line in Unix end of line (CR/LF to LF)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3891076/3776858)

Comment: The commands *are* identical; the *inputs* are not.

Comment: Also, see ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings) (short answer: yes, very sensitive).

Comment: It was not entirely obvious tome that was the cause, that's why I asked. Thanks.